# 3rd party app for hooking up a web based UI to server DB tables

Tags: sql-server, database, user-interface, web, analytics

I have a DB on my server with information on users, games, and stats, etc. In order to analyze and understand various stats, I need to perform both complex and simple queries cross-comparing tables in my DB. I don't have time to develop a user-friendly interface that allows me to perform queries and view results in a visual way. Can anyone recommend a good 3rd party solution for this ? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with SSIS? IMHO, if you need visualisation you can use SQL Server Reporting Services. You can even embed rdl reports in SSMS.

Comment: SSIS is for Microsoft SQL Server (Which I am not using) and way to complex to use for the person for whom this is for. Same with SSMS. And I don't think this solution is web based anyway.. that is software that runs on the windows server

Comment: Silly me, not SSIS, SSMS. But you already said you can't use that. If you are left with nothing but the system, powershell could help. Using powershell you should be able to issue SQL Server query and display the result or even redirect it to CSV. After that, open that CSV using Excel. If no Office is installed, open it on another computer, maybe even use a shared folder for that.

Comment: Thanks but I think I am not making myself clear.. Basically I need something like Flurry Analytics for a server-side Java app and associated DBs

Answer (score 0):

Try this opensource project to create web gui (CRUD)
to any datasource which support crud operations:
https://github.com/vku1/sqlweb